# How can I find out all the errors that can possibly be thrown by a block of PHP code?

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

**I want to know what errors can be thrown that I am not catching, for dynamic code - not static code. For example, my code may run without throwing any Exceptions for 10 years and then throw UncaughtException**

**I want to specifically (non-generically) catch every type of Exception that can be thrown by the methods I am using. How can I know what Exceptions MAY be thrown by these methods?**

I want to non-generically catch every type of error that can possibly be thrown for a section of PHP code.

Examples of exceptions that may be thrown:

```
PDOException
ExpiredException
```

Now I have this around everything:

```
try{
 ...
}catch(Exception $e){
 ...
}
```

I'd like to replace it with something like this:

```
try{
 ...
}catch(PDOException $e){
 ...
}catch(ExpiredException $e){
 ...
}catch(Exception $e){
 ...
}
```

I'd like to be confident that I am catching all different kinds of Exception that can be thrown by the methods in the section of code

And if I catch all Exceptions individually, will it be safe to remove this part?:

```
catch(Exception $e){
 ... 
}
```

Or are there methods which will simply throw Exception?

**My solution preference list (1 is the most-preferred solution):**

**1:** A flag I can turn on that will cause php.exe to warn me about each and every possible type of Exception that is not specifically being caught

**2:** A way to individually check each method and see what errors can be thrown. Is the documentation the only way to check? or is there some IDE or PHP block that will tell me which Exceptions may be thrown by individual methods?

Comment: To answer part 1, you can call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your script to log every error that occurs, regardless of whether you catch it or not.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26204483/1247781) covers how to capture all warnings as exceptions that you can then handle however you need.

Comment: Sure, but I want to know what errors can possibly be thrown by a section of code (or individually for each method) because some errors may need to be handled in specific ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP static code analysis tool, which detects uncaught exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268346/php-static-code-analysis-tool-which-detects-uncaught-exceptions)

Comment: My code is not static, so this is not helpful. Yesterday an ExpiredException was thrown for the first time, and it was handled by catch(Exception $e){ ... } in an inappropriate way. I added catch(ExpiredException){ ... } and now it will be handled appropriately if it occurs again. I want to know what errors might be thrown that I am not catching. For example, tomorrow a new kind of Exception may be thrown that I am not handling correctly. I'm using standard PHP code such as $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $dboptions);, but this can throw PDOException.

Comment: I have no line of code that says "throw new PDOException", but it can be thrown, so I want to catch it. I have no line at all that says "throw new anything", so I can't search my code for errors that are being thrown and not caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all exceptions without even call `try`.

```
function hello($e)
{
  if ($e instanceof PDOException){
  echo "something".
}else echo $e->getMessage();


}


set_exception_handler('hello');
```

this should catch all exceptions.

### UPDATE 2

I've edited the code so you know what exceptions will be thrown  using `get_class();`

```
class mycustomException extends Exception{} // making new exception
function hello($e)
{
    if ($e instanceof PDOException){ // exception already known
        echo "something";
}else{

        echo get_class($e); // get exception name.
    }


}


set_exception_handler('hello');
throw new mycustomException(); // throw exception that we made.
```

Comment: Cool, but I want to know what exceptions can possibly be thrown. Catching and handling the errors are another issue. For example, I only found out today that ExpiredException can be thrown by 1 of the methods. It was handled by the catch(Exception $e){ ... } which caused unexpected behavior. So I want to find out what else might be thrown that I don't know about.

Comment: you can catch ExpiredException or any other exception that you don't know when you are calling else, we've called $e instanceof PDOException in case that you would do something special with this exception.

Comment: That code catches PDOException. My point is that I do not know what kinds of Exceptions will be thrown, and I want to find out. I want to KNOW WHAT EXCEPTIONS WILL BE THROWN. This is very different from CATCHING A SPECIFIC EXCEPTION. I may not even want to catch any of them! I want to know what they are.

Comment: by calling get_class(); function you will be able to know which exception has been thrown. Anyway, I've edited the answer.

Comment: That's also interesting, but it's still completely unrelated to the question. I don't want to know what class of Exception HAS BEEN THROWN AFTER IT IS THROWN. I want to know what class of Exception CAN POSSIBLY BE THROWN for each method in my code. I want to handle each class of Exception non-generically. For 1000 lines of PHP with 100 methods, how can I know for each method, which classes of Exception I am not catching specifically?

Comment: What you can do is get all defined classes (Exceptions) 

print_r(get_declared_classes());

All classes (Exceptions) will be in an array. 

 I've read everything about what you want to do but its all what I found about it in php.net

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are talking exceptions, you already have the answer

```
try{
 ...
}catch(PDOException $e){
 ...
}catch(ExpiredException $e){
 ...
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo get_class($e); // get's the class of unrecorded exceptions.
   //catches any exceptions missed by the above
}
```

Now if you are talking about "errors" you can do is use a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

```
  if(!function_exists('myErrorHandler')){
      function myErrorHandler($severity, $message, $file = 'UNKNOWN', $line = 'UNKNOWN')
      {

         throw new ErrorException(
             $message,
             1,
             $severity,
             $file,
             $line
         );
      }

      set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
 }
```

What it does is convert all PHP errors to exceptions or rather to `ErrorExceptoins`.

Now you can go a step further and use these other two functions.

[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

AND

[set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

I'm actually working on porting what I use to it's own stand alone [github project](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/tree/master/Evo/Core/Error). Right after I finish my [eJinn](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/eJinn) project, which you may be interested in. eJinn is designed to build exception classes based off a config file, so you can have one error per exception file and unique error codes in a project.

Comment: These steps are exactly what I do in my projects.

Comment: Me too,  Check this out https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Core/Error/ErrorHandler.php

Comment: Nice, compatible with PHP7?

Comment: It should be, but my larger framework is not done ( I have to redo it actually, I plan to separate into separate repos ).  So I am not sure how well it will work outside of that.  It will take me some time to do that for the Error stuff.

Comment: In my index.php line 310 is where it is called from https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/index.php  It takes a callback that is a writer and a formatted, that way errors can be written to the screen, files, emails, etc...  It has some fall back so it will work without that too.

Comment: This doesn't help, because there may be more Exceptions that can be thrown that I don't know about, and they will be handled by the catch(Exception $e){ ... } part. I want to catch and handle every error non-generically. I only found out today that ExpiredException can be thrown by 1 of the methods. How can I find out what other kinds of errors might be thrown by the methods in my code?

Comment: The only way is to search through all your code for the the `throw new` calls. Otherwise, how else would you find them by "magic" there is no php function `show_all_errors_my_code_throws()`.  I suggest using an editor that lets you search in all the files, such as notepad++

Comment: The other thing I must say is this is not a DRY( Dont Repeat Yourself )  principle but instead WET ( Write everything twice )  Is there a specific reason you want to do this.

Comment: I can't search my code for Exceptions that will be thrown. There's not 1 line in my code that says "throw new PDOException", but there are several places where it may be thrown. I want to tailor my error handling for different types of errors, that's why I want to know what errors may be thrown. Putting try{ at the top and }catch(Exception $e){ ... } at the bottom is not enough. My code is dynamic, so there are errors that may be thrown that will not occur every time.

Comment: I'm the one with false beliefs?  lol, Sorry, but I am not the one that believes there is an acceptable answer to an impossible question.  There is no way to know what code you are using, only core functions, Lavavel, CI, Wordpress, Cake etc. there could be several thousand possible types of exceptions that could be thrown by "Your code"  Besides, that's not a nice tone to take with someone that is helping you with their time.  Yes some assumptions have to be made, those are not "beliefs".

Comment: If you're looking for a list of the "Built in Core Exceptions"  I suggest dropping the attitude and using "Google" This took all of 5 minutes to find. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838257/what-exception-subclasses-are-built-into-php

Comment: Are you trying to scare me with big numbers? I don't believe even some huge system like Facebook would have thousands of types of Exceptions that could be thrown, and I doubt there would be more than 10 or 20 kinds of Exception that could be thrown by my code. I want to know them all so that I can prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thousands may be a bit of a stretch but many systems put only one error code per exception class, and then use interfaces for grouping and catching them ( yes you can catch them based on interfaces they implement).  So surely their can be 100's.  And my 7+ years of PHP experience says you don't need to know them all, seems a bit obsessive compulsive to me, so who is bordering on, how did you put it "psychotic"

Comment: That's interesting but it doesn't get me any closer to solving my problem.

Comment: Also you're doing so much more work then you need to.  A better bet is to have the code Email you when some new exception happens, that way you can go and do some remediation.  You can try to predict every case, but you will always miss something, and you will have done so much more work for those things that never happen.

Comment: I said above that I found out today that ExpiredException can be thrown by 1 of the methods. This Exception was caught by the catch(Exception $e){ ... }, but it was not handled appropriately, so it caused unexpected behavior and I found out that it can be thrown. I realized that I don't know what Exceptions can be thrown by my code. Some other errors, which may never have occurred and may never occur, could also cause unexpected behavior if they are not handled appropriately.

Comment: How will I "miss something" if I have a list of every Exception that can possibly be thrown, and I handle each one appropriately? I will only "miss everything" if I follow your advice. I'm willing to spend time to prevent unexpected behavior, and I want my code to be a framework for future projects, so I want to do everything right the first time.

Comment: Well as it seems you know everything, and none of you code throws exceptions then you should just read this post as I said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838257/what-exception-subclasses-are-built-into-php which will give you all the exceptions in the core PHP libraries.

Comment: `have a list of every Exception that can possibly be thrown` yep and then something gets updated, and you have to go maintain that list. Besides I think you miss the point of Exception handing if none of your code uses it.  But I wont argue the point.  Here is an example, I have a piece of code I am writing, its apx 1000 lines and throws 27 exceptions.

Comment: Especially frameworks, they should throw them and and leave the catching up to the application.  But what do I know, I've only built hundreds of websites and several B2B services that do 100's of thousands of searches a minute.  The one for my employer does 180,000 searches per minute and 200 million per day, and that's not an exaggeration.  In fact that is conservative, as we have hit up to 210k per minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set callback function by using register_shutdown_function() which will call on every end of your php code execution. In this callback function you can check whether any error occurs or not using error_get_last().
For Example:

```
// Register shutdown function
register_shutdown_function("shutdownTracker");

// Define all error types you want to catch and handle
define('E_FATAL', E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);

function shutdownTracker() {
    $error = error_get_last(); // This will return empty if no error occurs while executing php code.
    if(!empty($error) && ($error['type'] & E_FATAL)) {
        // Write your code here to handle you error

    }
}
```

Note: You should include this code on top of your code.

Comment: I don't want to know when errors occur, I can handle that with catch(Exception $e){ ... }.

Comment: I want to know which errors can be thrown by the methods in my code. For example, I only found out today that ExpiredException can be thrown by 1 of the methods. It was handled by the catch(Exception $e){ ... } which caused unexpected behavior.